# How to use an STL container to hold template based shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, containers, shared-ptr

I want to construct a container to hold shared_ptrs which are template based. For example, I have:

```
template <class T>
class Data
{
    ....
};

template <class T>
struct DataPtr {
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Data<T> > type;
};

template <class T>
struct mapData {
    typedef typename std::map<std::string, DataPtr<T>::type > type;
};

mapData<int>::type data;
void func(const std::string& str, DataPtr<int>::type& sth)
{
    if (sth)
    {
        data[str] = sth;
    }
}
```

Now I have a few issues. The compiler does not allow me to use DataPtr::type when define mapData, error message is "expected a type, got ‘dataPtr::type". If I drop the type and use

```
template <class T>
struct mapData {
    typedef typename std::map<std::string, DataPtr<T> > type;
};
```

Then "data[str] = sth" does not pass ("no match for ‘operator=’").

What should be the correct way?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misplaced the positioning of the `typename` keyword:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, typename DataPtr<T>::type > type;
//                            ^^^^^^^^
```